# How to identify opponent user enable or disable video in quickblox ios

Tags: ios, quickblox, quickblox-android

How to identify opponent user enable or disable video in Quickblox SDK. Please give the solution or delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

You can check this with the WebRTC Stats reporting.
To start collecting report information do the following:

```
[QBRTCConfig setStatsReportTimeInterval:5]; // 5 seconds
```

And classes that adopt QBRTCClientDelegate protocol will be notified with

```
     - (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session updatedStatsReport:(QBRTCStatsReport *)report forUserID:(NSNumber *)userID {
            double audioReceivedBitrate = report.audioReceivedBitrateTracker.bitrate;
            double videoReceivedBitrate = report.videoReceivedBitrateTracker.bitrate;

            //You can check Bitrate of the received video.
           NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
           // Video receive stats.
           NSString *videoReceiveFormat = @"VR (recv) %@x%@@%@fps | (decoded)%@ | (output)%@fps | %@/%@ | %@ms\n";
          [result appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:videoReceiveFormat,
                              report.videoReceivedWidth, report.videoReceivedHeight, report.videoReceivedFps,
                              report.videoReceivedDecodedFps,
                              report.videoReceivedOutputFps,
                              report.videoReceivedBitrate, report.availableReceiveBandwidth,
                              report.videoReceivedDecodeMs]];
           NSLog(@"%@", result);


        }
```

For reference : [Quickblox API](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios#Manage_remote_media_tracks)

Comment: Hi @sohan, Thanks for your help. But it is not working. Please tell another solution.

Comment: what are you getting in videoReceivedBitrate when opponent disabled video? @ManikandanSundar

Comment: and screen goes to blank ?

Comment: Yes @sohan. the screen is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use System Notifications feature from QuickBlox SDK. For example, user will send system message with this event (disable camera) and other users will listen this event and do something needed action ([guide for Android](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#System_notifications))